# Setting up latest Spark distribution on Windows machine - which Hadoop version's binaries should I use?

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to set up the latest version of Spark - 3.4.1 on my Windows machine.

[image]

Setup instructions for Windows says that I need to:

1. Download hadoop version-specific copies of winutils.exe and hadoop.dll
2. Place them under a folder and point that to HADOOP_HOME env var
3. and add %HADOOP_HOME%/bin to Path

I did all of this for Hadoop 3.3 and I run into this error in Spark shell:

[image]

All online solutions to address this seem to reiterate the above 3 steps which I have already done and isnt helping.

My question: since the Spark download page says prebuilt for Hadoop 3.3, I assumed I need winutils.exe and hadoop.dll for Hadoop 3.3. IS this correct? Or should I get these for Hadoop 3.0 since the Spark bundle's file name says hadoop3?

If I should indeed use the files for HAdoop 3.3, what else is going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my suspicion was correct.
I used binaries for hadoop 3.0 and that solved the problem